# Best monitor for a gtx 1070

Tags: monitors

I want to change my 1080p 60 hrz low budget monitor.

I have a GTX 1070 and my choice would be a 24" 1080p 144hrz with g sync, for a dual screen. Using the old one for web browsing. 
I think with 27" 1440p 144 hrz I won't reach 100+ fps on AAA games with high settings, so it's pretty much useless. Am I right?

Other question : if I want to upgrade my graphic card in the next years, would another 1070 for an SLI work better than a single Gtx 1080? And what about 1080ti?

My specs :
Intel 6700k OC
Asus maximus VIII hero
Corsair vengeance 2x8 GB 3000 OC
Corsair hydro h115i 
Evga gtx 1070 SC gaming 3.0

Comment: As for the GPU, probably an 1180 (Volta-based) would be a better upgrade than a 1080 because of the usual architectural and production improvements.

Comment: What games and what settings are you targeting? Do you care about color accuracy? Backlight bleed? "Pet" features like USB hubs?

Comment: Overwatch, cs : go, World of Warcraft, tomb rider, GTA, the witcher 3 and some AAA or strategy games. But no COD or battlefield. I'd like to have great response time, and not awful color accuracy so I won't spent weeks to find a decent result. With volta next year, I think I will upgrade my GPU in the coming years.. So I'd better choose a good monitor. Perhaps I will need to cut TAA or MXAA and lower settings a bit, but I think it would be worth it in the end.  My choice could be an IPS 27" 1444p monitor 144 hrz with g sync. But I absolutly don't know which one. I don't care about USB.